# How can I add a page to a directory other than Pages or SitePages?

Tags: 2010

I can't seem to figure out how to add a page (web part page or article page) from a blank/team or publishing website. I tried copying the Site Pages and Pages list setup from the defaults, but this did not seem to work.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out - if you create a wiki library (document library) list you have the option of giving it a name / url.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in a Team site, whenever you create a Page, SharePoint would ask you where to put in this page byt giving you a drop down with all libraries.

You can also try adding the Page content type to the target library and try creating the page there.

Comment: Yes, but all I see is the SitePages directory - none of the other libraries I created.